# C++ Break out of a function at an early stage

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have two questions.

The first is about working with functions. I need to break out of a function at an early stage under a condition.

For example:

```
std::string concat(std::string& x, std::string& y, std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
    if (atoi(x.c_str()) < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else {
        std::string concatStr = y + x;

        top_back(vec);
        top_back(vec);

        return concatStr;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the function must return a string, but if the string x(which i of course convert to int) is less than 0, then I theoretically should break out of the function.

The problem with writing just `return;` is that the compiler tells me that it needs to return a value.

The second question is how can I remove the last line from the console?
That's connected with the first question, as someone suggested that `return "";`
is a good workaround, but it writes a blank space into the console, which in my case with the program I'm writing is not good and causes problems.

Comment: Do you have to use C++11?  If you can use C++17 you can use `std::optional` which is made for this use case.  If you have to stick with C++11 you could use `boost::optional` instead.

Comment: Nope, i don't have to.
How can i implement std::optional?

Comment: Well now i notice that even my compiler supporting C++17, it still keeps telling me that for the usage of std::optional, i need c++17.

Comment: Did you enable it?  If you are using gcc or clang you need to compile with `-std=c++17`

Comment: @NathanOliver Come on, `std::optional`? `return "";` is just fine, or better `return {};` if your compiler supports this. You're probably outputting the string like `std::cout << str << '\n';`, that would print an empty line. You just need to add one `if`: `if (!str.empty()) std::cout << str << '\n';`.

Comment: This looks like a contract violation: `concat`'s second argument  is supposed to be a non-negative integer but is in fact negative. In your little language, you now have a semantic error, much like changing a const value in C++ language: syntactically correct but not permitted semantically. I would suggest throwing an exception, something like `throw std::runtime_error(std::string("concat expects its second argument to be non-negative, the value provided was: ") + x.)`. Then in main() you catch it, print the message and exit with error. code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can compile using C++17 you can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to allow you to optionally return something from the function.  We would rewrite your function to

```
std::optional<std::string> concat(std::string& x, std::string& y, std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
    if (atoi(x.c_str()) < 0)
    {
        return {};
    }
    else 
    {
        std::string concatStr = y + x;

        top_back(vec);
        top_back(vec);

        return concatStr;
    }
}
```

And then in the call site you can use it like

```
auto ret =  concat(some, stuff, here)
if(ret) // only print if ret actually holds a string
    std::cout << *ret;
```

---

Alternatively you could use a `unique_ptr` and return an empty pointer if there is no result.  The function would change to

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> concat(std::string& x, std::string& y, std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
    if (atoi(x.c_str()) < 0)
    {
        return {};
    }
    else 
    {
        std::string concatStr = y + x;

        top_back(vec);
        top_back(vec);

        return std::make_unique<std::string>(concatStr);
    }
}
```

but the call site would remain the same.

---

Lastly if a blank string is never going to be a valid return from the function you could just return that and handle it in the call site like

```
std::string concat(std::string& x, std::string& y, std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
    if (atoi(x.c_str()) < 0)
    {
        return {};
    }
    else 
    {
        std::string concatStr = y + x;

        top_back(vec);
        top_back(vec);

        return concatStr;
    }
}


int main()
{
    //...
    auto ret =  concat(some, stuff, here)
    if(ret != "") // only print if ret actually holds a string
        std::cout << ret;
    //...
}
```

Comment: What would be the C++11 standard alternative?

Comment: @IvanStoianov One alternative before `optional` is to return a pointer instead and use dynamic memory.  `std::unique_ptr` makes that pretty easy and safe.

Comment: This might also be a decent case for `throw`ing an exception if negative numbers are uncommon enough to be called exceptional. Might also be worth [looking at  using `std::stoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) in place of `atoi`. Right now `atoi` failure is not being checked.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, just for the record, how do you delete the last line from the console (not in a container or an array)?

Comment: If you can't use c++17 there is also boost::optional (from which std::optional was taken).

Comment: @IvanStoianov I'm not sure what code you are using to display to the console so I couldn't say.  If you use an if statement like I do in the answer that should work.

Comment: `! ret.empty()` would be more correct than `ret != ""`.

Comment: I think `std::optional` is actually not that hard to implement (at least its basic functions)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not satisfied with C++17 solutions, it is possible to write your own `std::optional` implementation.

```
template<typename T>
class Optional
{
    bool m_HasValue;
    T m_Object;
public:
    Optional() : m_HasValue(false){};
    Optional(T&& Object) : m_HasValue(true), m_Object(std::forward<T>(Object)){};
    operator T&(){return m_Object;}
    operator bool(){return m_HasValue;}
    T& operator*(){return m_Object;}
};
```

This is a very simplified version of `std::optional`, but it will fulfill your needs.
Its usage remains the same as [in this post above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109355/c-break-out-of-a-function-at-an-early-stage/51109447#51109447).

```
using std::string;
Optional<string> DoSomething(string Input)
{
    if(Input == "dontprocessme")
        return {}
    // ... otherwise process the string
    string Output;
    // blah blah
    return Output;
}

// ...
auto RetString = DoSomething("processme");
if(RetString)
    std::cout << *RetString;
```